# C++ | 3x Linker Error LNK2028, 2019, 1120 | Constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, linker, linker-errors

I am getting 3 linker errors when I launch my windows desktop c++ clr project. I am using the Event Stream Client API by Mobotix (http://developer.mobotix.com/).

Errors:

```
error LNK2028: not listed token (0A000429) ""public: virtual __thiscall ie::MxPEG::MxPEG_SinkVideo::~MxPEG_SinkVideo(void)" (??1MxPEG_SinkVideo@MxPEG@ie@@$$FUAE@XZ)", which is linked in function ""public: __thiscall SinkVideo::SinkVideo(char const *)" (??0SinkVideo@@$$FQAE@PBD@Z)". C:\Users\Hecom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HKS\HKS\SinkVideo.obj   HKS

error LNK2019: link to not listed external symbol ""public: virtual __thiscall ie::MxPEG::MxPEG_SinkVideo::~MxPEG_SinkVideo(void)" (??1MxPEG_SinkVideo@MxPEG@ie@@$$FUAE@XZ)" in function ""public: __thiscall SinkVideo::SinkVideo(char const *)" (??0SinkVideo@@$$FQAE@PBD@Z)".    C:\Users\Hecom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HKS\HKS\SinkVideo.obj  HKS

error LNK1120: 2 not listed externs C:\Users\Hecom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HKS\Debug\HKS.exe  HKS
```

... I translated this error codes into English because I'm running the German version of Visual Studio.

When I comment out the following constructor in my SinkVideo.cpp, there are no more errors:

```
SinkVideo::SinkVideo (const char *outFile) {
}
```

as you see, the constructor is empty. so, why causes this errors?
could this be an error in the API?

Header-File (SinkVideo.h):

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "MxPEG_SinkVideo.hpp"
#include "MxPEG_Image.hpp"
#include "MxPEG_Defines.hpp"

using namespace ie::MxPEG;

class SinkVideo : public MxPEG_SinkVideo {
public:
    SinkVideo (const char *outFile);

protected:
    virtual
        MxPEG_ReturnCode doConsumeVideo(MxPEG_Image *buffer);

private:
    FILE * fVideoOut;
};
```

Source-File (SinkVideo.cpp):

```
#include "SinkVideo.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>


SinkVideo::SinkVideo (const char *outFile) {
    // the constructor which causes the errors
}

MxPEG_ReturnCode SinkVideo::doConsumeVideo(MxPEG_Image *buffer) {

    return er_Success;
}
```

Here is the code of the MxPEG_SinkVideo.hpp header file in the API:

```
#ifndef MXPEG_SRC_MXPEG_SINK_HPP_
#define MXPEG_SRC_MXPEG_SINK_HPP_

#include "MxPEG_Image.hpp"

namespace ie { namespace MxPEG
{

/*
 * Interface of the Vido Sink.
 *
 * Pass an instance of this to the constructor when creating an instance of MxPEG_SDK(). The SDK will pass all decoded video frames to the doConsumeVideo()
 * function of that instance.
 *
 */
class MxPEG_SinkVideo
{

protected:

public:

   virtual
   ~MxPEG_SinkVideo();

   MxPEG_ReturnCode consumeVideo(MxPEG_Image *buffer);

protected:
   friend class MxPEG_SinkSynchronized;

   /*
    * Receives each video frame right after it was decoded. Either YUV or RGB is possible (see MxPEG_Image.hpp and MxPEG_SDK_API.hpp)
    *
    * doConsumeVideo needs to take care of deleting the buffer once it is no longer needed.
    */
   virtual
   MxPEG_ReturnCode doConsumeVideo(MxPEG_Image *buffer) = 0;

};

} } /* namespace ie::MxPEG */

#endif /* MXPEG_SRC_MXPEG_SINK_HPP_ */
```

Comment: You get an error when you **link** your program. You can't launch it because it is not there.

Comment: You're probably building with /clr:pure.  Is there an explicit reason for that?

Comment: no, there isn´t an explicit reason. how can i change this? sorry, i´m new

Comment: Your linking is complaining about the destructor `~MxPEG_SinkVideo`, yet you show no definition for it.